# Lightbox: Other attribute for image description (instead of title)

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, lightbox, title

At the moment the lightbox uses the attribute title for the displayed description under the image. i want to use the title attribute for a tooltip and another for the lightbox image description.

can i just replace "title" to another attribute in the code:
https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/blob/master/js/lightbox.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just want to say that i habe found the part i was looking for where i can set the Attribute which is used for the lightbix title (line 135 in the lightbox.js):

```
function addToAlbum($link) {

        self.album.push({

          link: $link.attr('href'),

          title: $link.attr('data-title') || $link.attr('title')

        });

      }
```

so everything is solved.